# Android Java Sqlite Updating Error

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have been trying to update a record in my database, so i need to update just one peace of date in my database, and i want to do it where the name is equal to the name sent but I'm getting an error.

Here is my code:

```
//Update Data into table
public void updatePlanStock(String name, String under_text, String plan_image, String plan_duration, String plan_workouts_id, String plan_is_finished) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(Dbhelper.PLAN_NAME, name);
    cv.put(Dbhelper.PLAN_UNDER_TEXT, under_text);
    cv.put(Dbhelper.PLAN_IMAGE, plan_image);
    cv.put(Dbhelper.PLAN_DURATION, plan_duration);
    cv.put(Dbhelper.PLAN_WOKROUTS_ID, plan_workouts_id);
    cv.put(Dbhelper.PLAN_IS_FINISHED, plan_is_finished);
    database.update(Dbhelper.TABLE_PLAN_STOCK, cv, "_name="+name+"", null);
    //database.insert(Dbhelper.TABLE_PLAN_STOCK, null, cv);
    database.close();
}
```

Here is the error that I'm getting:

> no such column: TEST (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE plan_stock
>   SET
>   under_text=?,_name=?,is_plan_finished=?,workouts_id=?,duration=?,image=?
>   WHERE _name=TEST

Here is my code that creates the tables:

```
public class Dbhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {



    //Plan Information
    public static final String TABLE_PLAN_STOCK = "plan_stock";
    public static final String TABLE_PLAN_CUSTOM = "plan_custom";

    public static final String PLAN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String PLAN_NAME = "_name";
    public static final String PLAN_UNDER_TEXT = "under_text";
    public static final String PLAN_IMAGE = "image";
    public static final String PLAN_DURATION = "duration";
    public static final String PLAN_WOKROUTS_ID = "workouts_id";
    public static final String PLAN_IS_FINISHED = "is_plan_finished";





    //Table Information
    public static final String TABLE_WORKOUTS_STOCK = "workout_stock";
    public static final String TABLE_WORKOUTS_CUSTOM = "workout_custom";
    public static final String TABLE_WORKOUTS = "workout";

    public static final String WORKOUTS_ID = "_id";
    public static final String WORKOUT_NAME = "name";
    public static final String WORKOUT_BENEFIT_1 = "benefit_1";
    public static final String WORKOUT_BENEFIT_2 = "benefit_2";
    public static final String WORKOUT_BENEFIT_3 = "benefit_3";
    public static final String WORKOUT_TIME = "time";
    public static final String WOKROUT_REQUIRMENTS = "requirments";
    //workout info

    public static final String WORKOUT_ROUNDS = "workout_rounds";

    public static final String WORKOUT_ROUND_1 = "round_1";
    public static final String WORKOUT_ROUND_2 = "round_2";
    public static final String WORKOUT_ROUND_3 = "round_3";
    public static final String WORKOUT_ROUND_4 = "round_4";
    public static final String WORKOUT_ROUND_5 = "round_5";
    public static final String WORKOUT_ROUND_6 = "round_6";
    public static final String WORKOUT_ROUND_7 = "round_7";
    public static final String WORKOUT_ROUND_8 = "round_8";
    public static final String WORKOUT_ROUND_9 = "round_9";
    public static final String WORKOUT_ROUND_10 = "round_10";
    public static final String WORKOUT_ROUND_11 = "round_11";
    public static final String WORKOUT_ROUND_12 = "round_12";


    public static final String WORKOUT_REST_1 = "rest_1";
    public static final String WORKOUT_REST_2 = "rest_2";
    public static final String WORKOUT_REST_3 = "rest_3";
    public static final String WORKOUT_REST_4 = "rest_4";
    public static final String WORKOUT_REST_5 = "rest_5";
    public static final String WORKOUT_REST_6 = "rest_6";
    public static final String WORKOUT_REST_7 = "rest_7";
    public static final String WORKOUT_REST_8 = "rest_8";
    public static final String WORKOUT_REST_9 = "rest_9";
    public static final String WORKOUT_REST_10 = "rest_10";
    public static final String WORKOUT_REST_11 = "rest_11";
    public static final String WORKOUT_REST_12 = "rest_12";


    public static final String WORKOUT_REPS_1 = "reps_1";
    public static final String WORKOUT_REPS_2 = "reps_2";
    public static final String WORKOUT_REPS_3 = "reps_3";
    public static final String WORKOUT_REPS_4 = "reps_4";
    public static final String WORKOUT_REPS_5 = "reps_5";
    public static final String WORKOUT_REPS_6 = "reps_6";
    public static final String WORKOUT_REPS_7 = "reps_7";
    public static final String WORKOUT_REPS_8 = "reps_8";
    public static final String WORKOUT_REPS_9 = "reps_9";
    public static final String WORKOUT_REPS_10 = "reps_10";
    public static final String WORKOUT_REPS_11 = "reps_11";
    public static final String WORKOUT_REPS_12 = "reps_12";

    //for round
    public static final String WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_1 = "round_exercises_1_main";
    public static final String WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_2 = "round_exercises_2_main";
    public static final String WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_3 = "round_exercises_3_main";
    public static final String WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_4 = "round_exercises_4_main";
    public static final String WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_5 = "round_exercises_5_main";
    public static final String WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_6 = "round_exercises_6_main";
    public static final String WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_7 = "round_exercises_7_main";
    public static final String WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_8 = "round_exercises_8_main";
    public static final String WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_9 = "round_exercises_9_main";
    public static final String WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_10 = "round_exercises_10_main";
    public static final String WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_11 = "round_exercises_11_main";
    public static final String WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_12 = "round_exercises_12_main";

    public static final String WORKOUT_REPS_1_main = "reps_1_main";
    public static final String WORKOUT_REPS_2_main = "reps_2_main";
    public static final String WORKOUT_REPS_3_main = "reps_3_main";
    public static final String WORKOUT_REPS_4_main = "reps_4_main";
    public static final String WORKOUT_REPS_5_main = "reps_5_main";
    public static final String WORKOUT_REPS_6_main = "reps_6_main";
    public static final String WORKOUT_REPS_7_main = "reps_7_main";
    public static final String WORKOUT_REPS_8_main = "reps_8_main";
    public static final String WORKOUT_REPS_9_main = "reps_9_main";
    public static final String WORKOUT_REPS_10_main = "reps_10_main";
    public static final String WORKOUT_REPS_11_main = "reps_11_main";
    public static final String WORKOUT_REPS_12_main = "reps_12_main";

    public static final String WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_1 = "round_exercose_rest_1";
    public static final String WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_2 = "round_exercose_rest_2";
    public static final String WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_3 = "round_exercose_rest_3";
    public static final String WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_4 = "round_exercose_rest_4";
    public static final String WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_5 = "round_exercose_rest_5";
    public static final String WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_6 = "round_exercose_rest_6";
    public static final String WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_7 = "round_exercose_rest_7";
    public static final String WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_8 = "round_exercose_rest_8";
    public static final String WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_9 = "round_exercose_rest_9";
    public static final String WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_10 = "round_exercose_rest_10";
    public static final String WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_11 = "round_exercose_rest_11";
    public static final String WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_12 = "round_exercose_rest_12";

    public static final String WORKOUT_TYPE = "workout_type";


    public static final String WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_1 = "round_exercises_resp_deco_1";
    public static final String WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_2 = "round_exercises_resp_deco_2";
    public static final String WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_3 = "round_exercises_resp_deco_3";
    public static final String WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_4 = "round_exercises_resp_deco_4";
    public static final String WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_5 = "round_exercises_resp_deco_5";
    public static final String WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_6 = "round_exercises_resp_deco_6";
    public static final String WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_7 = "round_exercises_resp_deco_7";
    public static final String WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_8 = "round_exercises_resp_deco_8";
    public static final String WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_9 = "round_exercises_resp_deco_9";
    public static final String WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_10 = "round_exercises_resp_deco_10";
    public static final String WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_11 = "round_exercises_resp_deco_11";
    public static final String WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_12 = "round_exercises_resp_deco_12";

    //


    //database info
    public static final String DB_NAME = "WORKOUT.DB";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 2;

    //table creation

    public static final String CREATE_PLAN_STOCK = "create table " + TABLE_PLAN_STOCK+"("+PLAN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ PLAN_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"+ PLAN_UNDER_TEXT + " TEXT NOT NULL,"+ PLAN_IMAGE  + " TEXT NOT NULL,"+ PLAN_DURATION  + " TEXT NOT NULL,"+ PLAN_WOKROUTS_ID + " TEXT NOT NULL,"+ PLAN_IS_FINISHED  + " TEXT NOT NULL);";
    public static final String CREATE_PLAN_CUSTOM = "create table " + TABLE_PLAN_CUSTOM+"("+PLAN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ PLAN_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"+ PLAN_UNDER_TEXT + " TEXT NOT NULL,"+ PLAN_IMAGE  + " TEXT NOT NULL,"+ PLAN_DURATION  + " TEXT NOT NULL,"+ PLAN_WOKROUTS_ID + " TEXT NOT NULL,"+ PLAN_IS_FINISHED  + " TEXT NOT NULL);";


    public static final String CREATE_TABLE = "create table " + TABLE_WORKOUTS + "(" + WORKOUTS_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            WORKOUT_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_BENEFIT_1 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_BENEFIT_2 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_BENEFIT_3 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_TIME + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WOKROUT_REQUIRMENTS + " TEXT NOT NULL," +

            WORKOUT_ROUNDS + " TEXT NOT NULL," +

            WORKOUT_ROUND_1 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_2 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_3 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_4 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_5 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_6 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_7 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_8 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_9 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_10 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_11 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_12 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +


            WORKOUT_REST_1 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REST_2 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REST_3 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REST_4 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REST_5 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REST_6 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REST_7 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REST_8 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REST_9 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REST_10 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REST_11 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REST_12 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +

            WORKOUT_REPS_1 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_2 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_3 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_4 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_5 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_6 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_7 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_8 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_9 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_10 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_11 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_12 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +


            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_1 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_2 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_3 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_4 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_5 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_6 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_7 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_8 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_9 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_10 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_11 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_12 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +


            WORKOUT_REPS_1_main + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_2_main + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_3_main + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_4_main + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_5_main + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_6_main + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_7_main + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_8_main + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_9_main + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_10_main + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_11_main + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_12_main + " TEXT NOT NULL," +

            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_1 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_2 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_3 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_4 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_5 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_6 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_7 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_8 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_9 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_10 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_11 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_12 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_TYPE + " TEXT NOT NULL," +


            WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_1 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_2 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_3 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_4 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_5 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_6 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_7 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_8 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_9 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_10 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_11 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_12 + " TEXT NOT NULL);";


    public static final String CREATE_TABLE_STOCK = "create table " + TABLE_WORKOUTS_STOCK + "(" + WORKOUTS_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            WORKOUT_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_BENEFIT_1 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_BENEFIT_2 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_BENEFIT_3 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_TIME + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WOKROUT_REQUIRMENTS + " TEXT NOT NULL," +

            WORKOUT_ROUNDS + " TEXT NOT NULL," +

            WORKOUT_ROUND_1 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_2 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_3 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_4 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_5 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_6 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_7 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_8 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_9 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_10 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_11 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_12 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +


            WORKOUT_REST_1 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REST_2 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REST_3 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REST_4 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REST_5 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REST_6 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REST_7 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REST_8 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REST_9 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REST_10 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REST_11 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REST_12 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +

            WORKOUT_REPS_1 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_2 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_3 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_4 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_5 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_6 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_7 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_8 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_9 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_10 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_11 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_12 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +


            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_1 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_2 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_3 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_4 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_5 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_6 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_7 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_8 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_9 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_10 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_11 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_12 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +


            WORKOUT_REPS_1_main + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_2_main + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_3_main + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_4_main + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_5_main + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_6_main + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_7_main + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_8_main + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_9_main + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_10_main + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_11_main + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_12_main + " TEXT NOT NULL," +

            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_1 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_2 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_3 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_4 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_5 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_6 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_7 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_8 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_9 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_10 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_11 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_12 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_TYPE + " TEXT NOT NULL," +


            WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_1 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_2 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_3 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_4 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_5 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_6 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_7 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_8 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_9 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_10 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_11 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_12 + " TEXT NOT NULL);";



    public static final String CREATE_TABLE_CUSTOM = "create table " + TABLE_WORKOUTS_CUSTOM + "(" + WORKOUTS_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            WORKOUT_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_BENEFIT_1 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_BENEFIT_2 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_BENEFIT_3 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_TIME + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WOKROUT_REQUIRMENTS + " TEXT NOT NULL," +

            WORKOUT_ROUNDS + " TEXT NOT NULL," +

            WORKOUT_ROUND_1 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_2 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_3 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_4 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_5 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_6 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_7 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_8 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_9 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_10 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_11 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_12 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +


            WORKOUT_REST_1 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REST_2 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REST_3 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REST_4 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REST_5 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REST_6 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REST_7 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REST_8 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REST_9 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REST_10 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REST_11 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REST_12 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +

            WORKOUT_REPS_1 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_2 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_3 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_4 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_5 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_6 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_7 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_8 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_9 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_10 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_11 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_12 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +


            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_1 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_2 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_3 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_4 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_5 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_6 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_7 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_8 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_9 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_10 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_11 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISES_12 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +


            WORKOUT_REPS_1_main + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_2_main + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_3_main + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_4_main + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_5_main + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_6_main + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_7_main + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_8_main + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_9_main + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_10_main + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_11_main + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_REPS_12_main + " TEXT NOT NULL," +

            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_1 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_2 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_3 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_4 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_5 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_6 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_7 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_8 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_9 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_10 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_11 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_ROUND_EXERCISE_REST_12 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_TYPE + " TEXT NOT NULL," +


            WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_1 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_2 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_3 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_4 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_5 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_6 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_7 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_8 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_9 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_10 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_11 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            WORKOUT_EXERCISES_REPS_DECORATION_12 + " TEXT NOT NULL);";


    public Dbhelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_STOCK);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CUSTOM);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_PLAN_STOCK);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_PLAN_CUSTOM);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_WORKOUTS_CUSTOM);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_WORKOUTS_STOCK);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_WORKOUTS);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PLAN_STOCK);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PLAN_CUSTOM);
        onCreate(db);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the value of `where` clause in quotes other wise SqlLite engine would think its a column name.

Change

```
database.update(Dbhelper.TABLE_PLAN_STOCK, cv, "_name="+name+"", null);
```

to

> This is better, prevents [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

```
database.update(Dbhelper.TABLE_PLAN_STOCK, cv, "_name=?", new String[]{name});
```

or

```
database.update(Dbhelper.TABLE_PLAN_STOCK, cv, "_name='"+name+"'", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could Android let handle the text value

```
database.update(Dbhelper.TABLE_PLAN_STOCK, cv, "_name=?", new String[]{name});
```

or bind the string yourself by enclosing it with `'`

```
database.update(Dbhelper.TABLE_PLAN_STOCK, cv, "_name='"+name+"'", null);
```

With `_name=TEST` sql thinks `TEST` is a column of your table and not a text value.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to call the update method avoiding to put the full condition in the same string.

```
public int update (String table, ContentValues values, 
    String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)
```

So you could write all the where clauses without the value as

```
String[] args = new String[]{"value1", "value2"};
db.update(TABLE, newValues, "name=? OR name=?", args);
```

In your case you should change your code to

```
String[] args = new String[]{"name"};
database.update(Dbhelper.TABLE_PLAN_STOCK, cv, "_name=?", args);
```